# SQL update statement to update potentially multiple rows based upon date

Tags: sql

I am trying to update values in table A using table B, based upon the date in each table matching, example data below.

```
Table A                  
Date    Value            
May-21   0
Jun-21   0
July-21  0

 TABLE B
Date    Value            
May-21  8
Jun-21   6
July-21  7
```

The dates are dynamic and will change over time. Is there any way of creating an update statement which updates table A with the values based upon table B, where there are multiple dates which will change over time.

I have been hard coding the date in the where clause but this method i need to manually update the dates and have multiple update statements where there is one statement for each date.

Does anyone know if this can be achieved with a single update statement, or updates statements without hard coding the date. I would try a merge statement but the real table has data from lots of sources so ideally want an update statement as a more user friendly solution.

desired result:

```
 TABLE A
Date    Value            
May-21  8
Jun-21   6
July-21  7
```

Comment: Which sql database are you using? -  Update from other records /  tables is an extension of SQL - so there are different methods, depending on technology used.

Comment: I am using MS SQL server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In standard SQL, you can express this as:

```
update a
    set value = (select b.value from b where b.date = a.date)
    where exists (select 1 from b where b.date = a.date);
```

Many databases support a join of some type in `update`s.  However, the exact syntax depends on the database.